# Yii2 advanced template not working on shared hosting without yii serve

Tags: apache, deployment, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, shared-hosting

I'm working on Yii2 advanced template,
I want to run the project on shared hosting, after uploading and configuring the project on shared hosting it still showing directory content until I execute (Yii serve) command

how to run the project without yii serve command?

Comment: Are you sure all files are uploaded - htaccess files?

Comment: thanks @vvpanchev  .htaccess files wasn't uploaded to the server

Comment: So, already solved?

Comment: Yes @FahmiAuliya

Answer (score 0):

I use VirtualHost and my **DocumentRoot** is set up this way for frontend:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/mylink/frontend/web/
```

And this way for backend

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/mylink/backend/web/
```

with different **ServerName** for each one

Hope this help.